# Transferring maximum power to multiplexed loads

Tags: power, pcb, analog, multiplexer, transmission-line

I'm interested in creating a system driving 8 different loads from a single amplifier, at relatively high currents of few hundred mA

I wish to do this utilising a 8:1 multiplexer IC (8* spst), where each time, one of the loads will be driven to, and the other 7 switches will be shut. However I'm worried how the impedance mismatches from the closed switches will affect my power transfer

Ideally, I would use parallel resistors at each multiplexer input. But, I'm extremely limited for space, and this would of course also reduced the current I can deliver to each load.

Am I unnecessarily worrying about reflections? This is not a digital signalling system, and the length of the line is extremely small in compared to my signal wavelength. Really struggling for this, as this is not an example one can find in a text book.

Comment: What's your signal frequency and voltage amplitude?

Comment: Analog mux and few hundred mA does not sound compatible. Which mux and what are you trying to do? I don't think reflections are the first thing to worry about here.

Comment: @Justme I've already found the mux that meets the current requirements 200mA peak. I was surprised too!

Comment: @JonathanS. Few MHz 3 V p-p ish. Delivering a current of ~100mA.